# Why fatal error: 'yaml.h' file not found when installing PyYAML?

Tags: python, parsing, yaml, pyyaml

I'm trying out downloading PyYAML and install it following the instructions here http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML

So I downloaded the ZIP package: http://pyyaml.org/download/pyyaml/PyYAML-3.11.zip and then cd into that folder and run `python setup.py --with-libyaml install`, the error message I got is `ext/_yaml.h:2:10: fatal error: 'yaml.h' file not found`

But I checked the PyYAML-3.11 folder, the yaml.h is there...

UPDATE: I tried the methods here http://sandlininc.com/?p=500

`$ sudo easy_install pip`
`$ brew install libyaml`
`$ sudo easy_install setuptools`
`$ pip install -U PyYAML`

Then I tried the `python setup.py --with-libyaml install` again. I got the message **error: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_yaml.so: Permission denied**

Did I miss anything? Why the permission was denied? Thank you!

Comment: Which distribution are you on? and did you install the yaml development package that contains the yaml.h header file? If you're on Debian try as root: apt-get install libyaml-dev .

Comment: Hi thanks! I'm using osx...I've updated my question and am curious about why the permission denied??

Comment: Just an fyi, i think this is broken at least on Catalina (10.15.4) or sometime before that. I can't remember when it last worked though.

Answer (score 31):

You can solve the issue by reinstalling the pyyaml package after adding required dependent libraries. Following are the steps:

1. Uninstall pyyaml

`pip uninstall pyyaml`

2. Install below packages

`apt-get install libyaml-dev libpython2.7-dev`

3. Install pyyaml again

`pip install pyyaml`

Answer (score 3):

In `MacOS` the following solved the problem:

```
pip3 uninstall PyYaml
pip3 install PyYaml==5.2
```

Comment: Highly recommend against this as PyYaml 5.4 and below has [critical vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2020-14343/). My MacOS solution was to `brew install libyaml` for access to `yaml.h`